#  How to restore saved data when uninstalling  c# application

Tags: c#, sql, windows, visual-studio-2010

For example I have developed c# application (with sql database) and installed on win OS, then use to save some data. Now I need to install new window, what did happen with my saved data?

Comment: You can decide to remove or keep 'saved data' using some custom code in un/installer.

Comment: Don't remove the database during the uninstall? It's hard to answer when we don't know the behavior on your uninstall/upgrade procedure.

Comment: What do you mean by "install new window" ??

If by that you mean you reinstalled the windows operating system, and during the windows OS installation you did a fresh install (not upgrade), then you've most likely lost the data.

Comment: Normally data only goes if you create it as part of the install, and then maybe add/alter it as part of running. If like say word, its files made on the fly by the app, they shouldnt go at all

Answer (score 0):

Generally the data you are referring to might be either created during the installation or when the program itself is used (like an OLTP applicaiton). If lets say you have followed all the best practices and created the application using the created installation package, then the uninstaller should give you the option to either store your preferences like template and layout and such(if your program supprts those kind of things). But as for the data and even more in your case data stored in SQL is not deleted UNLESS you specifically mention in the uninstallation to drop the table or database. So as you are mentioning new window, just ensure the database exists and all the data is in contact(most likely it will be). Then also ensure that the new window is pointing to the data with all the necessary constrings and authentication.